# UILabel category block property crash when main thread checked

Tags: ios, crash

```
@interface UILabel (Chainable)
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UILabel *(^color)(NSString *value);
@end

@implementation UILabel (Chainable)
- (UILabel *(^)(NSString *value))color {
  return ^(NSString *value) {
    self.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor; // 
    return self;
  };
}
@end

UILabel *label = [UILabel new].color(@"0xffffff");
```

Why coding like this cause crash:

> Thread 1: EXCBADACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) when xcode -> edit scheme
> -> Diagnostics -> main thread checker is selected

Only crash when using debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the name. `-color` is an existing extension on UILabel. I believe it's been deprecated for longer than iOS has been public (`textColor` is from iOS 2), but it still exists:

```
dsdump /System/iOSSupport/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework | grep color\]
0x00000e95243 -[UILabel(UILabelDeprecatedMethods) color]
```

It just forwards to `-textColor`:

```
                     -[UILabel color]:
0000000000e95243         push       rbp                                         ; Objective C Implementation defined at 0x1629e80 (instance method), DATA XREF=0x1629e80
0000000000e95244         mov        rbp, rsp
0000000000e95247         mov        rsi, qword [0x1675228]                      ; argument "selector" for method _objc_msgSend, @selector(textColor)
0000000000e9524e         pop        rbp
0000000000e9524f         jmp        qword [_objc_msgSend_12b96d8]               ; _objc_msgSend, _objc_msgSend_12b96d8,_objc_msgSend
```

Making two extensions with the same method name is undefined behavior in ObjC, and you're getting the wrong one.

Without the main thread checker, or in release mode, I expect you're seeing that this is quietly doing nothing. When the main thread checker injects check-code, I expect things don't quite line up, which leads to the crash. (But this is all undefined behavior. Lots of things could happen. I haven't explored the compiler output to see exactly what does happen.)

You need to change the name of this extension.

Comment: And then there’s the time I named a property `firstResponder` and all hell broke loose...!

Comment: hahahahahahahah. Yeah, I once added a `-pop` method to NSMutableArray, and implemented it backwards of how Apple's private category works. Totally blew up UINavigationController. That one made me mad, though. Apple took `_` as their prefix. All their private categories should be prefixed. (I get why deprecated methods might not, but they shouldn't just add convenience methods without prefixes and then demand *we* prefix to avoid them.)

Comment: Thank you very much. It's very useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the name UILabel you can use UILabelCustom interface and implementations then you can call it like

```
UILabelCustom *label = [UILabelCustom new].color(@"0xffffff");
```

or then you can also inherit it to the native one UILabel